# Python 3.8 Nested varible not updating

Tags: python

I am trying to look for a folder & create it if it does not exist. Win 10
Creating the folder works fine if it does not exist but having issues with the last `else` statement.
I can't understand why the `num_start` variable updates but the `dir_look` variable does not.

If I use a while loop I get an infinite loop as it will always be true

PS, starting coding after a 40-year absence, it had rubber keys

## Find & if not create directory

```
import os

letters = input("Enter the first 3 letters : ")
letters = letters.upper()
num_start = 1
zero = "00"
num_start_len = len(str(num_start))
print("num start length is ", num_start_len)

dir_look = (r"C:\Users\user\Documents\FGC Client Drawings\\" + letters + zero + str(num_start))
check_for_folder = os.path.isdir(dir_look)
print(check_for_folder)

# working out how many zero digits required

if  num_start_len == 3 :
    zero = ""
    print("If" + zero)

elif num_start_len == 2 :
     zero = "0"
     print("elif" + zero)

else:
    print("else" + zero)

# make directory

if not check_for_folder :
        os.makedirs(dir_look)
        print("created folder : ", dir_look)

else:
    if check_for_folder:
        num_start += 1
        # os.makedirs(dir_look)
        print("Num start value", num_start)
        print(dir_look)

    else:
        print("end")

print(dir_look)
```

TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
Enter the first 3 letters : aaa   
num start length is  1   
True   
else00   
Num start value 2   
C:\Users\user\Documents\FGC Client Drawings\\AAA001   
C:\Users\user\Documents\FGC Client Drawings\\AAA001   

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: welcome back to the coding world!

Comment: you had a line with `num_start = num_start + 1` updating the variable `num_start`, but you never updated the variable `dir_look` in your code, therefore its expected that it wouldn't change

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also, `num_start = num_start + 1` can be shortened to `num_start += 1`.